# Get all records by records type mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
list_type      list_name
----------     ---------
city            Chicago
city            Houston
city            Philadelphia
city            Phoenix
state           Alabama
state           Alaska
state           California
state           Connecticut
state           Delaware
state           Florida
state           Georgia
color           Red
color           Green
color           Blue
```

when I run a mysql query, I need output like this, 
**without using of GROUP_CONCAT**

I don't have access in server to change group_concat maxlength which is default to 1024characters, so I need a query without using of group_concat.

list_type      list_name
----------     ---------
city         Chicago,Houston,Philadelphia,Phoenix
state        Alabama,Alaska,California,Connecticut,Delaware,Florida,Georgia
color        Red,Green,Blue

Comment: Why you don't want to use `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: i don't have access in server to change group_concat maxlength which is default to 1024characters, so i need a query without using of group_concat

Comment: Then do it in another language.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you set the temporary session-scope setting `group_concat_max_len`? You should be able to do this. But you should use it in every query call.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
select group_concat(column) from table group by column
```

or instead of `SET SESSION...` do this:

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```